# Angular realtime update values

Tags: angular, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application where the user can enter text and I would like all other users to have the same application open on different computers to be able to see this information.

Is there a way to do this without the help of a database like firebase or some api?

Ex: I insert text into the component and everyone can see it, or I click on a button that changes the screen background to green and everyone can see it.

Comment: I don't think there's any way for you to communicate the value of a text or background without using a database or an API.

Comment: No, you can't do it without any form of servers. You need to send the updated changes to a server. Then the server can forward that updated changes to other users.

Answer (score -1):

you can declare that on ngonit so whenever page reloads or component reloads so the data gets updated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will not achieve the result desired by OP